# difference between item added and item adding event handler in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

can any one please explain me when i use itemadded event handler and when to use itemadding event handler.

i dont know the actual difference between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ItemAdding is invoked before the event occurs and ItemAdded afterwards.

Comment: You can use it to perform any sort of pre-event tasks you need to, and you can even cancel the event.